# In MetaMask (web3.js 0.20.x) how to get events happened during a transaction?

Tags: web3js, metamask, contract-invocation

In MetaMask (web3.js 0.20.7) I send a contract method with `.sendTransaction()`.

Now I need to check the values of arguments of `UpdateItem` event created by this contract *during the call of this method*.

How?

My actual code:

```
    function createItem(string calldata _title,
                        string calldata _shortDescription,
                        string calldata _longDescription) external
    {
        itemOwners[++maxId] = msg.sender;
        emit ItemUpdated(msg.sender, maxId, _title, _shortDescription, _longDescription);
    }
```

```js
async function createNewItem() {
    const contract = web3.eth.contract(await categoriesJsonInterface());
    const contractInstance = contract.at(categoriesContractAddress);
    const title = document.getElementById('title').value;
    const short = document.getElementById('short').value;
    const long = document.getElementById('long').value;
    contractInstance.createItem.sendTransaction(title, short, long, {gas: '5000000'}, (error, receiptHash) => {
        web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(receiptHash, (error, receipt) => {
            console.log(receipt.logs)
            const event = receipt.logs.ItemUpdated;
            const itemId = event.returnValues.id;
            open('upload.html?id=' + itemId);
        });
    });
}
```

It aims to get information from a Web form and store it in the Ethereum logs.

Comment: Have you checked the receipt returned in the callback passed to this function?

Comment: @goodvibration The receipt is some big hexadecimal number (apparently the transaction hash). What to do with this value?

Comment: What is `ItemUpdated`?

Comment: @goodvibration `event ItemUpdated(address owner, uint256 indexed id, string title, string shortDecription, string longDescription);`

Comment: @goodvibration It seems I've found a solution: I can `.watch()` for the event before calling `sendTransaction()` and enumerate events till `.watch()` callback receives `transactionHash` equal to the transactionHash provided by `sendTransaction()`. Then it is an exercise to do it correctly in both cases if the event comes after or before `sendTransaction()` callback, to make things harder to do.

Comment: Following my answer, you simply did not bother to investigate the `logs` field deeply enough. You can get the event name via `logs[0].event` and the event parameters via `logs[0].args`. If there are several events, then you can of course get them using an index higher than `0`.

Answer (score 1):

On web3.js v0.x:

Function [web3.eth.sendTransaction](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/0.20.7/DOCUMENTATION.md#web3ethsendtransaction) returns a transaction-hash (either in a `Promise` object, or via a callback function passed as input).

You can take this transaction-hash and pass it to function [web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/0.20.7/DOCUMENTATION.md#web3ethgettransactionreceipt), which returns the receipt of that transaction (again, either in a `Promise` object, or via a callback function passed as input).

The receipt object includes a `logs` field, which contains all events emitted by your contract function.

Comment: It does not work: `receipt.logs` is an empty array despite the contract does emit an event during processing of the external call:
    contractInstance.createItem.sendTransaction(title, short, long, {gas: '5000000'}, (error, receiptHash) => {
        web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(receiptHash, (error, receipt) => {
            console.log(receipt.logs);
            const event = receipt.logs.ItemUpdated;
            const itemId = event.returnValues.id;
            open('upload.html?id=' + itemId);
        });
    });

Comment: @porton: Obviously, since you haven't posted any of your code, I cannot help you any further in that. How exactly am I supposed to reproduce this, when I have no idea what function you are trying to execute, how this function is coded, how it emits the event, and what this event even looks like???

Comment: From the docs: "Note That the receipt is not available for pending transactions." Thus before retrieving the data I need to wait till the transaction completes. How to wait for this? My code just calls a contract method that emits an event and does nothing other.

Comment: I've posted the code and what I am trying to do.

Comment: @porton: You can get the event name via `logs[0].event` and the event parameters via `logs[0].args`. If there are several events, then you can of course get them using an index higher than `0`.

Comment: In my code `console.log(receipt.logs)` prints `[]`. So there are no `log[0]`.